# Создание и вывод информации views.py DRF

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

Есть объект "книга" под которой есть комментарии пользователей.

models.py

```
 class Books(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
        author = models.ManyToManyField(Authors, related_name='authors',)
        genre = models.ManyToManyField(Genres, related_name='genres',)
        info = models.TextField(max_length=1000, blank=True)
        publisher = models.ForeignKey(Publishers, related_name='publisher', 
        on_delete=models.SET_DEFAULT, default=1)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.name
    
    class Comments(models.Model):
        book =  models.ForeignKey(Books, on_delete=models.CASCADE,  related_name='comments_book')
        user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.COSCADE)
        text = models.TextField(max_length=1000)
        date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        
        def __str__(self):
            return '{}: {}'.format(self.user, self.text)
```

serializers.py

```
class BookSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ['name', 'author']

class CommentSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Comments
        fields = ['user', 'text', 'date', 'book']

class BookDetailSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    comments = CommentSerializer(many=True, source='comments_book')
    author = AuthorSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)
    class Meta:
        model = Books
        fields = ['name', 'author', 'genre', 'publisher', 'comments']
```

views.py самая обычная на пока

```
class BookDetailView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BookDetailSerializer
```

Как реализовать, что бы данные на странице отображались одним запросом, но при том можно было отправлять POST запросы для оставления комментариев.
Имею ввиду, вот что получаем на примере ниже:

```
{
"count": 1,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"results": [
    {
        "name": "It",
        "author": [
            {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Стивен Кинг",
                "country": "USA",
                "bio": null,
                "image": null
            }
        ],
        "genre": [
            1
        ],
        "publisher": 1,
        "comments": [
            {
                "user": 2,
                "text": "good book",
                "date": "2021",
                "book": 1
            },
            {
                "user": 1,
                "text": "i realy like it",
                "date": "2021",
                "book": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

т.е. на одной странице мы получаем данные и по книге и по комментариям к ней, но как создать вьюху, которая бы позволяла ещё и записывать в комментарии прям на этой же странице. Если об этом есть информация в мануале по дрф, прошу ткнуть туда пальцем. Или тут должен быть другой способ?

Answer (score 0):

Не знаю на сколько это корректное решение.
Переопределил вьюхи через ViewSet

```
class BookDetailView(viewsets.ViewSet):

def list(self, request, pk=None):
    queryset = Books.objects.all()
    obj = get_object_or_404(queryset, pk=pk)
    serializer = BookDetailSerializer(obj)
    return Response(serializer.data)

def create(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    serializer = CommentSerializer(data=request.data)
    serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
    serializer.save()
    return Response(serializer.data,
                    status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED,
                   )
```

Странно, что никто не мог мне хотя бы этого посоветовать.